# Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am having some trouble since I added the react-native navigation drawer package. I have looked at a ton of things on SO and GitHub and so far most are just saying to add to babel and clear cache. I also tried not having it in my babel config, but then I get error 2 below.

All I want to be able to do is use the react-native-drawer package to allow me to have drawer and stack navigation - different packages, but need both.

Sorry for not much info, but I am new to React/React-Native and clueless on what is useful. Just ask, and I will provide it as an edit.

Error message 1 (with current babel config)

> index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'
  ],
  plugins: [
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin"
  ]
};
```

package.json

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.3",
```

error 2 (without plugin in babel config)

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

This error goes away if I comment out the drawer lines

Comment: where are you building iOS or android? Did you reset caches?

Comment: @Fapi I am using iOS currently and did try without cache

Comment: once you configure your bable.config file , you must have to clean your gradle and do hard reset

Answer (score 0):

**The 1.13.3 don't need config the babel plugin.**

Check your project root if you have config your babel.config.js file?
if you find code like this, delete it:

```
    module.exports = {
    presets: [],
    plugins: [
        [
            'react-native-reanimated/plugin', {
                relativeSourceLocation: true,
            },
        ]
    ],
};
```